# Dynamically add a constant value to a Ruby instance

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm testing a module (`Foo::Api::Utility`) by creating a dummy instance.  The module references a constant that has been defined by the class that `includes` it (`self.class::BASE_URL`).

I'd like to be able to access this value and set it.

This doesn't work:

```
before(:each) do
  @utility = Object.new
  @utility.extend(Foo::Api::Utility)
  @utility.const_set('BASE_URL','https://domain.tld/api/v1')
end
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why would you expect this constant to be accessible via `Foo::Api::Utility` module?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question, but you might have been after `@utility.singleton_class.const_set('BASE_URL','https://domain.tld/api/v1')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
before(:each) do
  @utility_class = Class.new
  @utility_class.include(Foo::Api::Utility)
  @utility_class.const_set('BASE_URL','https://domain.tld/api/v1')
  @utility = @utility_class.new
end
```

---

Or, in more succinct manner:

```
before(:each) do
  @utility =
    Class.new do
      include Foo::Api::Utility
      const_set :BASE_URL,'https://domain.tld/api/v1'
    end.new
end
```

Comment: `@utility = Class.new { include Foo::Api::Utility; BASE_URL = 'https://domain.tld/api/v1' }.new`?

Comment: Passing block to Class initializer is nice, I'll try to remember it.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I like your suggestion.  I wasn't aware that this could be done.

Comment: My suggestion does effectively the same as the original answer provided by @MarcinKołodziej. I took the responsibility to update the answer, providing my variant.

Comment: When the code reaches the reference to the constant (`url =  "#{self.class::BASE_URL}/resources/"`) in the class that includes the module, it generates an error: `uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00007fcc58832698>::BASE_URL`.

Comment: Well, seems like the solutions are not the same after all. `const_set` does work, while defining `BASE_URL` in block defines it level higher instead of in Class initializer block.

Comment: @craig fixed; sorry for misleading edit, I would blame ruby for that :)